# Can I configure MS email client to send email but not receive?

Tags: windows-10, outlook-2013

I am setting up a POS system that requires the sending of email for receipt purposes, so I would like to have Outlook configured without error, but I absolutely do not want incoming email.  This is a POS system and the users are ID 10 T compliant.  I have killed all network access except what is required for OS/application updates, but still would like to allow the sending of email without receiving.  I can just edit out the incoming email server, but will receive errors which I am trying not to.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should configure the mail address/inbox this way, not the client.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention it's Godaddy, and configuration is extremely limited.  I also want to still be able to receive email from this account, but on a different client.

Comment: Is it possible to create an additional mailbox for this POS client to use, then configure forwarding (at GoDaddy) to direct inbound email to the address that is being received on the other machine. I can't see any simpler way of doing it. Often you see "no-reply@" style addresses that don't allow replies at all but I doubt you can configure GoDaddy to reject inbound emails on a valid mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using ms-outlook then you can follow the [link](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/config/how-to-create-a-fake-pop3-account/) to setup send only outlook account depending on your outlook version